# Stop tracking .suo file in Sourcetree

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to stop tracking .suo file in sourcetree. It was appearing in **unstaged files** so I right-clicked and selected 'Stop Tracking'. now this file is in **staged files** section. Also in Visual Studio it is showing as deleted.

[image]

Under staged in source tree when I right-click the Ignore option is disabled.

[image]

Note: I have also added *.suo in gitignore manually. This is a feature branch and the master branch still has .suo file. I want to keep it locally but remove from git.

Comment: When you want to stop tracking a file, you need to commit a deletion of this file from a git repository standpoint (even if the file is still there in working directory). So that's normal. Commit that and after verify that the file is ignored (i. e. doesn't appear in 'Changes section' anymore)

Comment: After deletion, i also had to go to sourcecontrol and stoptracking then ignore the file. after that I did a stage and commit of the gitignore file...now it looks fine